# Compiling ARM in Windows with Eclipse

Tags: c, gcc, arm

I would like to make C program for the cortex - M0 processor. I work with 64-bit window machine and Eclipse. I found many things on internet and I am confused:
1.MinGW
2.ARM GCC compiler for windows (which can be set in the advanced system in computer, the PATH variable)
3. ARM GNU compiler from Eclipse market

Among all this , Which compiler can be used for ARM and can I output my results on command line. i.e Can I compile the program and produce results on the console ?

This result below is what I get when I try to compile a hello program using the command: arm-none-eabi-gcc -o -tesres -test.c

```
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/6 2017-q1-update/bin/../lib/gcc/ar
m-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-exit.o): In functio
n `exit':
exit.c:(.text.exit+0x2c): undefined reference to `_exit'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/6 2017-q1-update/bin/../lib/gcc/ar
m-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): In functi
on `_sbrk_r':
sbrkr.c:(.text._sbrk_r+0x18): undefined reference to `_sbrk'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/6 2017-q1-update/bin/../lib/gcc/ar
m-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-writer.o): In funct
ion `_write_r':
writer.c:(.text._write_r+0x24): undefined reference to `_write'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/6 2017-q1-update/bin/../lib/gcc/ar
m-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-closer.o): In funct
ion `_close_r':
closer.c:(.text._close_r+0x18): undefined reference to `_close'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/6 2017-q1-update/bin/../lib/gcc/ar
m-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-fstatr.o): In funct
ion `_fstat_r':
fstatr.c:(.text._fstat_r+0x20): undefined reference to `_fstat'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/6 2017-q1-update/bin/../lib/gcc/ar
m-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-isattyr.o): In func
tion `_isatty_r':
isattyr.c:(.text._isatty_r+0x18): undefined reference to `_isatty'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/6 2017-q1-update/bin/../lib/gcc/ar
m-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-lseekr.o): In funct
ion `_lseek_r':
lseekr.c:(.text._lseek_r+0x24): undefined reference to `_lseek'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/6 2017-q1-update/bin/../lib/gcc/ar
m-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-readr.o): In functi
on `_read_r':
readr.c:(.text._read_r+0x24): undefined reference to `_read'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Which CM0 device exactly you are compiling? ARM-GCC can work just fine.

Comment: Actually my doubt is , which combination i have to use. I havent compiled on the processor, I am just trying to set up environment. I wish to output my results on console.

Comment: What combination you are talking about?

Comment: I mean, I setup the eclipse normally, I downloaded the Eclipse ARM compiler from market. I guess, this must be enough for compiling the program and flash on it. I want the output on console, is this possible to do ?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to compile things like CMSIS or the ARM ABI on a PC. You'll have to skip those files. Overall you won't be able to compile a _complete_ ARM project. You have to keep all the low-level things away.

Comment: you appear to be trying to compile an application that expects an operating system, but have none (cortex-m).  what is your test program some sort of printf helloworld?  try blinking an led instead.

Comment: windows has nothing to do with this nor eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ARM GNU compiler from Eclipse marketplace. When this is installed, you can Create a new C/C++ project with the correct Project type -
 e.g. `Executable/STM32F0xx C/C++ project` if that's the series of chip you wish to target. Make sure Trace output in the wizard is NOT set to `None (no trace output)`. You can then use `trace_printf` to write to host console via ST-LINK, as the hello-world example will show.

You may also have to install and configure OpenOCD to capture that output and display it in Eclipse's console. In Eclipse, you just set up an external tool `Run > External tools > External tools configuration`. Specify the location of openocd.exe, set the working directory and, in Arguments, specify which devkit you're using by using the appropriate config file, e.g. `-f board\stm32f072discovery.cfg`.

Then build, run OpenOCD and debug.

Answer (score -2):

Under Windows for M0 I've been using **IAR Embedded Workbench**, which was a nice and smooth experience for me. But as far as I remember it needed a license.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ARM_Cortex-M_development_tools

Maybe you should look for free options in this list.

Comment: Non related with question.

Comment: @tilz0R There are a lot of questions in topic post, and one of them was "Which compiler can be used for ARM" for which I provided a list of options, recommending the option I had experience with. Can you elaborate a little bit more as to what in my post was not related?